# Difference between onPeriodicNotification and onMarkerReached - Android

Tags: android, audiorecord

I want to record the audio continuously and send it to a device on network. I dont want to miss audio captures when Sending is taking place. So I tried my hands on 'OnRecordPositionUpdateListener'.

In that, I came across 'onPeriodicNotification' and 'onMarkerReached'. I am not able to know how exactly these 2 differ from each other functionally. I searched on net a lot about these 2 methods, but couldnt find any clear explanation.  Can someone please throw some light on this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

onPeriodicNotification = periodic, which means to be used when the AudioRecord has to notify the OnRecordPositionUpdateListener multiple times with a certain regularity

onMarkerReached = a notification is sent only once at a certain marker.